# Delete additional files when cleaning project

Tags: visual-studio

When executing build->clean solution in Visual Studio 2005 I want to also remove some debug text files that may exist in my build directory. The file name will always be the same, i.e. debug.txt. Is there a way to get Visual Studio to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Project->Properties and choose configuration properties. 
THere's an entry "Extensions to delete on clean". Add *.txt to it and that just should do the trick. Or you can explicitly specify debug.txt